# C# how to check if DateTime Object value is someday

Tags: c#, datetime

C# how to check if DateTime Object value is someday

```
 public static string GetBalance(DateTime date)
    {
if (date = 3/23/2021 || date = 3/22/2021)
{
do somthing
}
    }
```

Comment: `date.Date == new DateTime(2021, 3, 23)`?

Comment: @Llama Another way of saying that is: `=` != `==` (did I just do that?)

Comment: @Charlieface Not sure. OP doesn't seem to have any idea how to do it at all. Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To compare two dates without time:

```
public static string GetBalance(DateTime date)
{
    DateTime firstDateToCompare = new DateTime(2021, 3, 22);
    DateTime secondDateToCompare = new DateTime(2021, 3, 23);
    if (date.Date == firstDateToCompare.Date || date.Date == secondDateToCompare.Date)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need the `.Date` part on the two dates you create in the method, since their time component will already be zeroed.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
if (date == DateTime.Parse("2021-03-22") || date == DateTime.Parse("2021-03-23"))
```